# How use handle function that return window.location.pathname in cypress?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have some function that return windows.location.pathname, then I transform this function
and based on result make some data transformation, but when I run cypress tests, instead
of windows.location.pathname I get some cypress object, so If I want use window.location
how I should handle it in cypress (e2e tests )

```
const getLocaleBeforeFlowsLoaded = (location = history.history.location) => {
  const locale = location.pathname.split('/')[1]
// get error here since we have "__cypress" instead of locale above
  const priceFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  })
 
  return priceFormatter
}
```

I suppose it happens because cypress doen't ready by this moment, since in other places it works fine, it's just function that started before app started

Comment: Please the code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the location from the wrong window.

The `history` variable gives you the test runner location (hence `__cypress` in URL), but the app under test is in an `<iframe>` so it has a different set of global `window`, `location`, etc.

Try this

```js
const getLocaleBeforeFlowsLoaded = (location) => {
  const locale = location.pathname.split('/')[1]
  const priceFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  })
 
  return priceFormatter
}

cy.visit(...)

cy.location().then(location => {
  const priceFormatter = getLocaleBeforeFlowsLoaded(location)
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

based on cypress [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location) :

```
 cy.location() // Get location object
 cy.location('pathname') // Get the path name of the location object
 cy.location('port') // Get the port of the location object
 ...
```

Comment: Updated my question, I think I need something like mock but not getting actual location, but I am not sure(